# How to re-export datatype from functor argument in Standard ML

Tags: types, module, sml, functor

Is it possible in Standard ML to re-export the constructors of a datatype that's part of a structure received as a functor argument. Some code will probably make this easier to understand:

```
signature FLAG =
  sig
    type t
  end

signature MEMBER =
  sig
    structure Flag : FLAG
  end

functor Member(F : FLAG) : MEMBER =
  struct
    structure Flag = F
  end

structure M =
  Member(struct
    datatype t =
      FLAG_1
    | FLAG_2
  end)

val flag1 = M.Flag.FLAG_1;
(* Error: unbound variable or constructor: FLAG_1 in path M.Flag.FLAG_1 *)
```

The above example may not make any sort of practical sense, but it's just a watered down version of an issue that I encountered in one of my projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, the unelaborated type specification in the `FLAG` signature entails that `t` is left opaque, and thus inaccessible for anything outside of the structures that implement `FLAG`.

Generally speaking, in SML, if a signature specifies an interface for a module, then the only parts of that module that can be accessed from without are those which are explicitly described in the signature. As you likely know, if you specify an interface for some module, then only those functions and values you explicitly declare in the signature are provided for use; all those which are omitted become sealed inside the module. The same principle is at work here with the unexplained specification of `type t`: since the signature does not give any account of how this type is constituted, no information about it is available.

So you *can* easily re-export the value constructors from a module given as a parameter to a functor, provided you have included those constructors in the specifications of that module's interface. E.g.,

```
signature FLAG =
sig
    datatype t = FLAG_1 | FLAG_2
end

signature MEMBER =
sig
    structure Flag : FLAG
end

functor Member(F : FLAG) : MEMBER =
struct
    structure Flag = F
end

structure M =
Member(struct
        datatype t =
                 FLAG_1
               | FLAG_2
        end)
```

And then

```
- val a = M.Flag.FLAG_1;
val a = FLAG_1 : ?.t
```

The most important point to take note of here is probably this: the inaccessibility of the value constructors in the module implementing `FLAG` have everything to do with the way the interface is specified and nothing to do with the fact that it appears here as a parameter to `functor Member`. We get the same behavior you observed when you were using a functor with the following program:

```
signature FLAG =
sig
    type t
end

structure F : FLAG =
struct
    datatype t =
             FLAG_1
           | FLAG_2
end
```

And then

```
[opening ~/Programming/sml/scratch/scratch.sml]
signature FLAG = sig type t end
structure F : FLAG
val it = () : unit
- F.FLAG_1;
stdIn:63.1-63.9 Error: unbound variable or constructor: FLAG_1 in path F.FLAG_1
```

Comment: Thanks. You're totally right. I got carried away with my project and missed the fact that it happens whenever the type is left unspecified in a signature. In my particular case I have two different `FLAG` structures, with two different `datatype` declarations, so I can't really define a signature. Thanks again.

Comment: I think (hope!) your case should be able to be achieved! Maybe with correct use of `where`? The SML module system is one of most exciting PL constructs I've been exposed to, but often and in many directions, I feel limitations and encounter hurdles making it clear that the module system is not quite what I want it to be. I am still trying to figure which parts are limitations imposed by the language implementation, and which parts are hard limits of well formedness and logical correctness.

Comment: I was able to work around it by using a pattern that I call the mixin pattern, where I simply `open` the result of a `functor` invocation. https://gist.github.com/igstan/c566eecc38784216f1499bfe8d91f4c4

Comment: Ah yes! I suspected it might involve `open` somehow, but I wasn't quite able to think of how, as I kept thinking about opening the module *inside* the functor.